# Delete two lines before a specific pattern using sed

Tags: bash, sed

Not much familiar with sed, I'm trying to delete 2 lines before a pattern (a timeout value and an empty line) and then reinsert both lines with updated timeout.

Here's a part of the yaml file that I've:

```
- id: phase1
  blahblahbal
  timeout: 720

- id: phase2
  blahblahbalh
  timeout: 1800
```

I'm trying to update first timeout to '900'.

Here's what I've with grep:

```
grep -v "$(grep -B 2 'id: phase2' test.yaml | grep -v 'id: phase2')" test.yaml > test.yaml
```

and then inserting updated value with sed. This is working but the grep doesn't look nice. Is there a way to delete the two lines with sed before a pattern?

Expected output after first sed/grep:

```
- id: phase1
  blahblahbal
- id: phase2
  blahblahbalh
  timeout: 1800
```

Expected output final:

```
- id: phase1
  blahblahbal
  timeout: 900

- id: phase2
  blahblahbalh
  timeout: 1800
```

Comment: Show your expected output.

Comment: Deleting relative to a pattern is hard, doubly so when the pattern follows what needs to be deleted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How is that comment helpful?

Comment: Your expected output has no lines deleted? You have just replaced the number. Is that what you actually want?

Comment: It's the final output.

Comment: What about using awk and making some kind of cycle buffering?

Comment: Yes, now I'm looking into awk :)

Comment: Sorry, looking at your expected output I realized: you just want to replace timeout values? For this, sed should be sufficient. But I'm rather sure that I misunderstood it somehow.

Comment: No problem. Actually there are multiple timeouts in the file and I want to update the timeout under 'phase1'. I think I might need two seds here. Do you think it can be done with a single sed?

Comment: So, you want to replace `timeout: 720` if (and only if) `- id: phase2` is matched?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it could be done using awk (`back-replace2.awk`):

```
$1 ~ /timeout:/ { lineTimeOut = NR }
/^[ \t\r]*$/ { lineEmpty = NR }
/- id: phase2/ {
  if (lineTimeOut == NR - 2 && lineEmpty == NR - 1) {
    buf1 = "  timeout: 900"
  }
}
{
  if (NR > 2) { print buf1 }
  buf1 = buf2 ; buf2 = $0
}
END {
  if (NR >= 2) { print buf1 }
  if (NR >= 1) { print buf2 }
}
```

The line numbers of a `timeout:` line and an empty line are remembered. Thus, it can be checked whether these lines appeared exactly two lines before / one line before the line where the remarked pattern (here `- id: phase2`) matches.

The variables `buf1` and `buf2` are used to make some kind of cycle buffering (i.e. the third last line is echoed for every line).

Therefore, the `END` rule is necessary to echo the rest of input (the contents of cycle buffers).

Test:

```
$ cat >back-replace2.txt <<EOF
- id: phase1
  blahblahbal
  timeout: 720

- id: phase2
  blahblahbalh
  timeout: 1800
EOF

$ awk -f back-replace2.awk back-replace2.txt 
- id: phase1
  blahblahbal
  timeout: 900

- id: phase2
  blahblahbalh
  timeout: 1800

$
```

Notes:

1. I didn't check the edge cases (e.g. whether files with less than 3 lines are handled correctly).
2. The pattern matching and replacement may need additional logic. I'm sure the questioner will be able to adjust the script appropriately.

Comment: Thanks @Scheff. I found another way as well (added as an answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution with sed:

```
# Remove above two lines before phase2 id
sed -i ':a;N;s/\n/&/2;Ta;/\n- id\: phase2$/s/.*\n//;P;D' test.yaml

# Add updated timeout
sed -i "/- id\: phase2/ i\\
    timeout: 900\\
" test.yaml
```

Comment: I know that sed has a lot more than just s (substitute) but I was never able to master it. Though, due to the existance of awk, my motivation is quite low...

Comment: Lol, I just copied the first sed from somewhere else. Didn't get what is actually happening in that command.